# Apache Url Rewrite or mask to remove extensions as .php

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to url rewrite in my Apache but I'm not sure which one it is. For example if someone goes to `www.example.com` clicks on a tab in there, and by default it would be `www.example.com/profile.php`
How can I rewrite it for `www.example.com/profile`/ or better, `www.example.com` without `/profile/`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP} on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl
RewriteRule ^ – [F]

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} foo=(.*)
RewriteRule ^grab(.*) /search.php?query=%1
```

Comment: Have you already tried to rewrite this url?

Comment: Yes, Ill attach my code. And another thing how can I rewrite the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I rewrite it for www.example.com/profile/ **or better, www.example.com without /profile/**

Your "better" approach is flawed. People like bookmarks. Omitting the `/profile/` from the URL will prevent link sharing and bookmarks. Sites grow on easy link sharing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)\/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

You can test this rule here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Okay, but is it still possible? My main reason was only for the home page after login for example: 
example.com/index.php -> login.php -> exmaple.com/main.php
How could I keep just that main.php as example.com/

Comment: It depends how your application is designed. But omitting the file name (or some form of identifier) from the URL is no.

Comment: For example how would facebook do it? As when you logout its index.php, when you login its still index.php

Comment: Perhaps something like `if( isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) ) { /* Get logged in logic */ }`